# Rolling Cashflow - Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a dynamic rolling 12 month cash flow in Excel.

Lets say the month name is in cell A1.

Underneath cell A1 l have a list of cash flow expenses in my rows and the expenses listed in the columns by month. I have a separate column at the end that totals up 12 months of expenses based on the month name (in cell A1).

So, if cell A1 says Jun-18, l want to add up the expenses for each row item from Jun-18 to May-19. OR say, if cell A1 says Sep-18, l want to add up the expenses for each row item from Sep-18 to Aug-19.

I don't know how to do this, can anyone please advise.

Thanks for your help,

M

Comment: ? So **all** the data is in column **A**, both the month name and the values to be added??

Comment: Show us your current efforts so far, please.  If you're not interested in doing the coding yourself, you should hire a coder then instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum ofset match

Given the example data below (as I think that you have described in your question), you can use the the following formula (this example the formula result is showing in B2) A1 contains the start date to calculate from.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A2,MATCH(A1,A2:A100)-1,4,12,1))
```

You will need to research how ofset works, as I currently do not have time to explain, but to help you use this formula within your worksheet you will need to change the number 4 which is 4th column away (column E containing the months totals) from the matched date.

The 12 in the formula shows how many rows down you want to sum.

```
            A          B           C           D           E 
    1    Jul-18     8638.21         
    2               Expence1    Expence2    Expence3    Total
    3    Jan-18     1           1           1           3
    4    Feb-18     2           2           2           6
    5    Mar-18     3541        531         51          4123
    6    May-18     100000      31          351         100382
    7    Jun-18     846         8           321         1175
    8    Jul-18     1           153         12          166
    9    Aug-18     0           8           21          29
    10   Sep-18     0           65          8           73
    11   Oct-18     54          321         1           376
    12   Nov-18     321         123         1           445
    13   Dec-18     1           321         2           324
    14   Jan-19     546         0           51          597
    15   Feb-19     132         51          15          198
    16   Mar-19     12          321         51          384
    17   Apr-19     51          123         321         495
    18   May-19     5161        3.21        351         5515.21
    19   Jun-19     21          3           12          36
    20   Jul-19     321         1           1351        1673
```

Comment: I wasn't too sure, as the question is not too clear, but it may help someone who stumbles across this question in the future.

Comment: Although the formula can be adapted to work across the columns if required.

Comment: Thanks for your help. l managed to figure out a solution but 'll give your version a go too. Thanks again, M.

Comment: @Miles, Please post your solution as an answer so to help anyone in the future who has a similar question. Not only will you be helping the community but you will be adding positively to your reputation.